# Read a memory stream

Tags: vb.net, serialization, memorystream

I have serialize class with 7 variable which are being written to a memory stream and then inserted into a database field. The 7 variable are all four bytes and there may be hundreds of records combined together before being written to the database. This works successfully.

However when I get the data back from the database and deserialize it:

```
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While rdr.Read()
        arr = rdr("BINPROFILE")
        ms.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length)
        ms.Position = 0
        SER = bf.Deserialize(ms)
    End While
```

My variable 'SER' which an implementation of the class containing the 7 variables, only reads the first 7 variables.

How do I loop through an entire memory stream and read all the data it contains?

Comment: Do you want to read the stream to byte(), string?

Comment: You'll have to call Deserialize() repeatedly to retrieve the other ones.  Not storing *one* object per table row in the dbase is in general a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

SER is overwritten in every iteration of the loop leaving you with just the value from the last record.  You need to save these in a array or list or work with then within the loop.

```
SER = bf.Deserialize(ms)
```

This line will replace whatever was in the SER variable with a new value, in your case, the 7 variables.

Comment: I suspected that I needed to call Deserialize() for each 28 byte block of data, however if I move the ms.Position by 28 bytes, I get an error "The input stream is not a valid binary format". I can't find any examples of how you loop through the serialized data, but I did copy the `SER = bf.Deserialize(ms)` line three times and sure enough it retrieves each group of data. I agree with Hans, I probably shouldn't strictly store data like this, but the nature of the data and the way it fits in with the contents of the table